# Filter Data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below :

```
[TMP_TBL] 
(
    ... 
    [DT_REFUND] [varchar(20)] NULL,
    [MSG_PROCESS] [nvarchar(max)] NULL,
    ... 
)
```

and it contains data like this:

```
| DT_REFUND | MSG_PROCESS    |
| A-BC---D  | WRONG DATETYPE |
| 20180301  | NULL           |
| 20180331  | NULL           |
```

When I do a query like:

```
select * 
from TMP_TBL 
where isnull(MSG_PROCESS, '') = ''
```

everything goes fine.

But when I do query like:

```
select * 
from TMP_TBL 
where isnull(MSG_PROCESS, '') = ''
  and convert(DATE, DT_REFUND) >= convert(DATE, '20180301');
```

I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Why did this happen, and how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should have avoided using `VARCHAR` data type for dates.

For the current scenario, you can use `TRY_CONVERT` like following.

```
select * 
from TMP_TBL 
where isnull(MSG_PROCESS, '') = ''
and TRY_CONVERT(DATE, DT_REFUND) >= convert(DATE, '20180301');
```

As your date column is `VARCHAR`, so there is a possibility of having empty spaces also, to handle this you can try `RTRIM` function before converting to date like following.

```
TRY_CONVERT(DATE, RTRIM(DT_REFUND)) >= convert(DATE, '20180301');
```

Answer (score 0):

First you check the value in the column is `DATE` format or other format, using `ISDATE` function. And compare with the date value.

If it is not in date format it returns `NULL` value.

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TMP_TBL 
WHERE ISNULL(MSG_PROCESS,'') = '' 
    AND CONVERT(DATE, CASE WHEN ISDATE(DT_REFUND)=1 THEN DT_REFUND ELSE NULL END) >= CONVERT(DATE, '20180301');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to filter out null values and compared date via `cast()` or `convert()` function

```
select * 
from TMP_TBL 
where MSG_PROCESS is null and
      cast(DT_REFUND as date) >= '20180301';
```

This assumes `null` value has always date as your sample data  suggests

In other way, first you could check `DT_REFUND` has some kind of date format data via `TRY_CONVERT()` function. So, your where clause should do

```
where MSG_PROCESS is null and TRY_CONVERT(date, DT_REFUND) is not null and
          cast(DT_REFUND as date) >= '20180301';
```

However, the above has some redundant filtration before `cast` so you could also express that as

```
where MSG_PROCESS is null and TRY_CONVERT(date, DT_REFUND) >=  '20180301';
```